Circom errors while compiling for composite using NAND
I'm trying to compile a Circom circuit using the following command:
circom composite.circom --r1cs --wasm --sym --c

However, I'm encountering several errors that I can't seem to resolve:

Unrecognized argument in include directive:
error[P1009]: unrecognized argument in include directive
┌─ "composite.circom":3:1
│
3 │ pragma circom 2.0.0;
│ ^^^^^^ this argument

I used pragma circom 2.0.0; at the top of my file to specify the version. Is there a different syntax or way to specify the Circom version?

Missing semicolon:
error[P1008]: Missing semicolon
┌─ "composite.circom":6:19
│
6 │ signal private s1;
│                  ^ A semicolon is needed here

I'm not sure why this error is appearing since I have already placed a semicolon after s1.

Illegal expression:
error[P1012]: illegal expression
┌─ "composite.circom":6:22
│
6 │ signal private s1;
│                   ^ here

I'm unsure what this error is referring to. The syntax seems correct based on my understanding.


Has anyone encountered these issues before or can suggest what might be going wrong? I'm using Circom version 2.0.0. Any help would be appreciated!
The Code is given below:
include "Nand.circom";

pragma circom 2.0.0;

template Composite(){
    signal private s1;
    signal input s2;
    signal input s3;
    signal output s5;
    signal s4;

    component G1 = NAND();
    component G2 = NAND();

    s1 ==> G1.a;
    s2 ==> G1.b;
    G1.out ==> G2.a;
    s4 ==> G2.b;
    G2.out ==> s5;
}

component main = Composite();


There are several issues here, let's start with the main error about pragma:

You have an include "Nand.circom"; at the top, but instead you must have the pragma circom 2.0.0; at the top! Simply switch their places. That solves your problem (1).

The problems (2) and (3) are due to private not being used in Circom anymore, all signals are assumed to be private unless they are specified to be public within the main component instantiation.

Signal s3 is not being used, and signal s4 is being used without initialization, that former will be a warning but latter will be an error. Perhaps s3 was supposed to be used instead of s4?


With the points above, I think this is kind of what we are looking for:
pragma circom 2.0.0;

include "Nand.circom";

template Composite(){
    signal input s1;
    signal input s2;
    signal input s3;
    signal output s4;

    component G1 = NAND();
    component G2 = NAND();

    s1 ==> G1.a;
    s2 ==> G1.b;
    G1.out ==> G2.a;
    s3 ==> G2.b;
    G2.out ==> s4;
}

component main { public [ s2, s3 ]}= Composite();

